# Reading config file that does not begin with section

Tags: python, python-2.7, configparser

I have config file that looks something like:

```
#some text 
host=abc
context=/abc
user=abc
pw=abc

#some text
[dev]
host=abc
context=/abc
user=abc
pw=abc

[acc]
host=abc
context=/abc
user=abc
pw=abc
```

I would like to parse the cfg file with ConfigParser in Python 2.7. The problem is that the cfg file does not start with the section. I cannot delete the text lines before the sections. Is there any workaround for that?

Comment: You could probably inject a section prior to parsing the file, but that sounds quite hacky to me. I would rather suggest you have a look at the [ConfigObj](https://pypi.org/project/configobj/) package. Much more flexible, and allows for parsing keys without headers. I use it for most of my projects, and I would personally never go back to using `ConfigParser`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject a section header of your choice.

```
import ConfigParser
import StringIO


def add_header(cfg, hdr="DEFAULT"):
    s = StringIO.StringIO()
    s.write("[{}]\n".format(hdr))
    for line in cfg:
        s.write(line)
    s.seek(0)
    return s


parser = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
with open('file.cfg') as cfg:
    parser.readfp(add_header(cfg, "foo"))
```